# Installing curl package in R-3.5.1

Tags: r, curl, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to install the `curl` package in R-3.5.1.  I am on Mac OSX 10.13.6 and using Homebrew as my package manager.  E.g.

```
> install.packages("curl")
Installing package into ‘/Users/user/.R/3.5.1-lib’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/cran/src/contrib/curl_3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 367047 bytes (358 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 358 KB

Looking for libraries in : ~/.R/3.5.1-lib....
* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/Users/user/.R/3.5.1-lib/curl’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/0s/qch_8kr55x91vgc08sfvh82w0000gn/T/RtmpP4GQji/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("curl") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Following their suggestions, I have libcurl in a reasonable system level directory, `/usr/lib`, i.e.

```
$ find /usr/ -name "*libcurl*" -print
find: /usr//sbin/authserver: Permission denied
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.8/libcurl.pc
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.9/libcurl.pc
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.10/libcurl.pc
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.11/libcurl.pc
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.5/libcurl.pc
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.14/libcurl.pc
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.13/libcurl.pc
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.12/libcurl.pc
/usr//lib/libcurl.dylib
/usr//lib/libcurl.4.dylib
/usr//lib/libcurl.3.dylib
```

I have `pkg-config`, i.e.

```
$ which pkg-config
/usr/local/bin/pkg-config
```

I also have set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, i.e.

```
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr//local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/
```

I have also tried the suggestion setting `INCLUDE_DIR` and `LIB_DIR` directly, i.e.

```
$ R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/curl/ LIB_DIR=/usr/lib' curl
Looking for libraries in : ~/.R/3.5.1-lib....
Warning: invalid package ‘curl’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
```

I am at a complete loss here. I'm not as familiar with developing on OSX, so maybe I'm missing something here.  Looking back at a previous install of R-3.4.2, it seems that I didn't have difficulties installing this package previously.

QUESTION: How do I get the `curl` package installed?  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082543/curl-package-not-available-for-several-r-packages) seems to be related, but is for Linux.